# ext news v5 error: Tx_News_Domain_Repository_NewsRepository

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I made a hook function for extension linkhandler with the following code:

```
$extbaseObjectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');

/**
 * @var $newsRepository \Tx_News_Domain_Repository_NewsRepository
 *
 */
$newsRepository = $extbaseObjectManager->get('Tx_News_Domain_Repository_NewsRepository');
```

in news v 4.3.0 this works.

Now I get the error:

> Could not analyse class: "Tx_News_Domain_Repository_NewsRepository"
>   maybe not loaded or no autoloader? Class
>   Tx_News_Domain_Repository_NewsRepository does not exist

What should I do to get the news repository in v5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use new syntax

```
/**
 * @var $newsRepository \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository
 *
 */
$newsRepository = $extbaseObjectManager->get(\GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository::class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use instead the namespaced name `\GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository` as the other one has been removed with 5.0.0